# How to Render Attachments (images) in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have attachments (images) for an object and here's how I am querying for my data from the object.

```
public List<SObject> getResults () {
    Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    List<SObject> results = [SELECT Id, 
                                    Name, 
                                    URL__c,
                                    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments)
                                    FROM MyCustomObject__c 
                                    WHERE 
                                    Id = :id];
    return results;
}
```

This is how I am rendering this data in visualforce

```
<apex:repeat var="c" value="{! results }">
                <div class="typeHeader">
                    {! c.Name}
                </div>

                <apex:outputText rendered="{! c.URL__c != null }">
                    <h3>URL</h3>
                    <div class="vulnDescrip">
                        {! c.URL__c}
                    </div>
                </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

How can I render the attachments similar to how I am rendering URL__c and Name?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Case.attachments}" var="att">

                <apex:panelgrid columns="1">
                    <h1>Image/h1>
                    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.id)}"/>
                </apex:panelgrid>
    </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query related attachments body in one soql.

Query child attachments in separate soql.

```
Attachment att = [Select Id, Body, Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :results[0].Id];
```

You can have a public variable to encode its value as

```
public String image {get;set;}
image = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(att.body);
```

Refer this image in vf page as:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{!image}" />
```

Comment: We don't need the body here. This can be achieved without query body.

Comment: How can we achieve this without query body?

Comment: @Illusion SFDC champ's  answer will work.

Comment: Yes. The other answer will work.